# Angular Material toolbar click event not logged?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have the following stackblitz demo where I'm experimenting with Angular Material (Attempting to log clicks on the hamburger icon):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-toolbar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I've assigned the click event handler to the toolbar like this:

```
 <my-toolbar menu='open($event)'>Your Toolbar</my-toolbar>
```

It's defined like this within the app component:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  open(event) {
    console.log("CLICK");
  }
}
```

However the clicks do not get logged.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parenthesis around the menu event handler. 
 Do the following.

```
<my-toolbar (menu)='open($event)'>Your Toolbar</my-toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks - Forgot parenthesis around the menu event emitter (Been a long day).

Answer (score 1):

I saw your stackblitz, you are emitting event but in your template you just missed the parenthesis to your "menu" output

```
 <my-toolbar (menu)='open($event)'>Your Toolbar</my-toolbar>
```